# Override text in group by clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a large table of data with descriptions that have been inconsistently entered. I'm trying to figure out how to include this field in a query and still group the records even if the descriptions don't match. In the example below I don't necessarily need the longest description, even if the result returns whatever description happens to be first that's fine. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT PartNumber, Description, Sum(TotQtySold), year
From partsTable
GROUP BY PartNumber, Description, year

PartNumber|Description|TotQtySold|year
ABC123    |Repair Kit |5     |2007
ABC123    |kit        |3     |2007
ABC123    |Repair kit |8     |2007

Desired Result
ABC123    |Repair Kit |16    |2007
```

Comment: Simply `MAX(Description)`? (And remove Description from GROUP BY clause.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't `GROUP BY` by that column.  Instead, `SELECT` the `MAX()` of that column...

```
SELECT PartNumber, MAX(Description), Sum(TotQtySold), year
From partsTable
GROUP BY PartNumber, year
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `Description` from `GROUP BY` clause  and use `min/max` or use `subquery` instead

```
select PartNumber, 
       (select top 1 Description 
        from table 
        where PartNumber = t.PartNumber and 
              year = t.year
        order by Description desc) as Description, -- remove order by clause if you want whatever Description
       Year
from table t
group by PartNumber, year;
```

However, i don't recommand to use `Description` column in `GROUP BY` clause which has long description.